# Cannot Find the DrRacket IDE

Tags: racket

Hi Guys? Newbie Question here. I am getting started with How to Design Programs. I need the DrRacket IDE to follow through the book but I cannot seem to get a hold of it from the website.

The install I got opens a command prompt. How do I get the DrRacket GUI part to start, or which package should I install.[Racket Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyRKp.png)

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: @uselpa I am using Windows 10.

Comment: when I installed my copy, it created a Start menu group called "Racket" for me (under "All Programs"), with the "DrRacket" item, that runs "C:\Program Files\Racket\DrRacket.exe". Try finding this executable, and if you do, you can start it by typing "DrRacket" at your command prompt: "C:\Program Files\Racket> DrRacket". I'm on different version of Windows, but it should be similar, for you.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks, your suggestion worked for me.

Comment: @WillNess, you can provide this as an answer for the next guy who might have the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I installed my copy, it created a Start menu group called "Racket" for me (under "All Programs"), with the "DrRacket" item in it, that is set up to run "C:\Program Files\Racket\DrRacket.exe".

Try finding this executable, and if you do, you can start it by typing "DrRacket" at your command prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\Racket> DrRacket
```

I'm on different version of Windows, but it should be similar, for you.